# Show that $|G|=24$, where $G$ is the Rotations of the Cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, 3d, rotations

I am looking at this problem from a visual stand point, Many of the explanations that I have found online invoke the multiplication principal of counting; basically, there are $6$ faces, and $4$ possible rotations if you fix any $1$ of the faces, thus, there are $6\times 4=24$ possible rotations that fix the cube's structure.

This does not seem right.  If you fix a face of the cube, then you are naturally fixing another face opposite of it.  So if face $1$ is opposite face $6$, rotating face $1$ counterclockwise $90$ degrees is the same as rotating face $6$ counterclockwise $270$ degrees.  Thus, this would only be $12$ of the total rotations permitted.

From there then, looking at a drawing of the cube i made, I think the next $12$ possible rotations come from the following.  There are $8$ vertices.  If we fix vertex $1$, then we naturally also fix vertex $8$ across from it.  There are only $2$ rotations then, and with $4$ pairs of vertices, this gives another $8$ rotations different from the original $12$.  However, I'm not sure where the final $4$ are coming from.

Is there an "easier" way of looking at this to visually convince me that $|G|=24$?  Am I incorrect about my intuition about the multiplication principal?

Comment: Orbit-Stabiliser.

Comment: This may help: http://garsia.math.yorku.ca/~zabrocki/math4160w03/cubesyms/

Comment: "rotating face 1 counterclockwise 90 degrees is the same as rotating face 6 counterclockwise 270 degrees" ~ I am not sure it is right.

Comment: Aside from the "do nothing" rotation, it might help to split the ("do-something") rotations into three categories, depending on the rotation axes: through opposite faces, through opposite edges, and through opposite vertices. (For face-rotations: there are only three "do-something" rotations per pair of faces, not four; you've counted "do-nothing" four times).

Comment: Visually: Assume each face of the cube has a letter A to F drawn on it. How many different pictures can you take of the cube, face-on? 24. There are six faces, and four different orientations per face. Now, replace the camera with a sci-fi holographic x-ray device, or assume the cube is made of transparent material, and we take a full wraparound picture or hologram of it. How many different ones can we take? 24, again: when we completely fix one face, we fix all the others, too; but we count each unique orientation as one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume the cube as $[{-1},1]^3$. There are

- the identity,
- $3$ rotations ($\pm 90^\circ$, $180^\circ$) around each of the $3$ coordinate axes,
- $2$ rotations  ($\pm 120^\circ$) around each of the $4$ space diagonals,
- $1$ rotation ($180^\circ$) around each of $6$ axes through the midpoints of opposite edges.

Answer (score 5):

One way of looking at it is by considering the *diagonal lines* inside the cube. For example:

[image]

There are four diagonals within the main cube. Any symmetry of the cube will permute these diagonals. So, there are a total of $4! = 24$ total symmetries of the cube.

Comment: Of course one also has to see that every possibly permutation is obtainable from a rotation of the cube, and that this rotation is unique. But then this argument no only shows $|G|=24$, but even that $G\cong S_4$