# Isometry of cube in $\mathbb R^4$?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, solid-geometry, platonic-solids

Find the Symmetry Group of : Tetrahedron and Cube.

I know that there is a duplicate question [Symmetry group of Tetrahedron](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493568/symmetry-group-of-tetrahedron)

but my professor suggested us to write coordinates of both cube and tetrahedron in  $\mathbb R^4$ and after see what happen. My question is:

> how can I write coordinates of cube and tetrahedron in this way?

I don't know where to start this problem sorry if I have not published my attempt.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You should start by writing down the coordinates of the unit cube in the plane (that's a square) and then in three dimensions. For the triangle, consider the points in space where the plane $x+y+z=1$ meets the coordinate axes. Then do the same for the cube and the three dimensional tetrahedron.

Comment: Well, a tetrahedron can be nicely embedded in $\mathbb R^4$ as (1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1). At least this makes its symmetry more apparent. As for the cube, I don't see how is $\mathbb R^4$ going to help us.

Comment: @EthanBolker ok i think i have got for tetrahedron i have to consider the plane  x+y+z+t=1 and find where it meet coordinate axis , and this can be done in (1,0,0,0) etc , but i didn't get the point on teh cube and how this mehod should help me. can you explain to me?

Comment: That's right, x+y+z+t=1.

Comment: @IvanNeretin ok so now can i do as i did in $\mathbb R^2 $? find 2 vector indipendent and see all the possible positions in the figure?  in this way if this is also valid here i would have teh canonic base of $\mathbb R^4$ and i have all 48 positions? Or maye something like this?

Comment: What 48? There are 24 permutations of the 4 vertices, and these are exactly the isometries of the tetrahedron.

Comment: @IvanNeretin ops yes sorry 4! my mistake ahaha for the cube instead ? using $\mathbb R^4$ can give me any sort of help? my professor said that a lot of times using higher dimension you can solve your your problem. i would like to find isometry of cube in a fast way

Answer (score 2):

The four permutations of $(1,0,0,0)$ form a tetrahedron. For a matrix $P$ to turn basis vectors into basis vectors, each column of $P$ must be a basis vector, and if $P$ is invertible they must be distinct, which means $P$ must be a permutation matrix. Conversely all $4!=24$ permutations work as isometries.

A cube in 3D may be described as the points $(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$. This has two inscribed tetrahedra, corresponding to the vectors with either an even or odd number of minus signs.  A cube in 4D may be described as the points $(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$ with an even number of minus signs - note then the subsets of points $(1,\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$ and $(-1,\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$ within this form two tetrahedra. The $24$ permutations still work as isometries, but now we may include multiplication by $-1$ as an isometry for a total of $48$ (which is the correct number, as we can work out using the orbit-stabilizer theorem). This makes the symmetry group $S_4\times C_2$.